# my table doesn't completely close all the borderlines

Tags: tables

using this lines for making a table, I noticed that it doesn't close all the border lines, and also I wanted to make the vertical line before the alpha character `\alpha`, thick or double, just don't know how to do that.

here is the code

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twoside,openright]{report}

\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{tabu}


\pagestyle{empty}



\begin{document}

\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\begin{tabu}{|[1.5pt]c|*{5}{c|}c|[1.5pt]}
\tabucline[1.5pt]{-}
\multicolumn{7}{|[1.5pt]c|[1.5pt]}{\textbf{Model Parameters}} \\ \tabucline[1.5pt]{-}
             D11(Nm) & D12(Nm) & thickness(mm) & $\alpha$ & Corrugation length & Deflection(mm) & Weight \\ \hline
            36 & 35 & 0.5 & 60 & 210 & 0.33 & SR4 \\ \hline 
              36 & 35 & 0.5 & 60 & 210 & 0.33 & SR4  \tabucline[1.5pt]{-}
        \end{tabu}
        \caption{The Parameters of the Model}
        \label{table:t43}
    \end{table}    

\end{document}
```

Comment: It does not even compile ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The OP is missing a `\\` before the last `\tabucline` command.

Any table package I know requires a `\\` (apart from the first line) for `\hline` - like statements (unless multiple of them occur in a row)

For my taste there are **too** much lines in the table.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twoside,openright]{report}

%\usepackage{setspace}  % not needed
%\usepackage{graphicx} % not needed
%\usepackage{tabularx} % not needed
\usepackage{tabu}


\pagestyle{empty}



\begin{document}

\begin{table}[H]
  \centering
  \begin{tabu}{|[1.5pt]c|*{5}{c|}c|[1.5pt]}
    \tabucline[1.5pt]{-}
    \multicolumn{7}{|[1.5pt]c|[1.5pt]}{\textbf{Model Parameters}} \\ \tabucline[1.5pt]{-}
    D11(Nm) & D12(Nm) & thickness(mm) & $\alpha$ & Corrugation length & Deflection(mm) & Weight \\ \hline
    36 & 35 & 0.5 & 60 & 210 & 0.33 & SR4 \\ \hline 
    36 & 35 & 0.5 & 60 & 210 & 0.33 & SR4 \\
    \tabucline[1.5pt]{-}
  \end{tabu}
  \caption{The Parameters of the Model}
  \label{table:t43}
\end{table}    

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thank you so much ,actually I have to add another line, so I ll have 3 lines of data !! I don't know if this is the best design for that , the thing is , the first two collumns are my variables and the other should change with respect to them , but I could not make them more outstanding , I mean the design of table not making bold

Comment: OP: take a look at the `booktabs` package for a couple examples of nice table formatting.

Comment: @Farzad64: Erik's suggestion is quite good.

Comment: thank you all for your helps, but that booktabs , did you mean I search it here for the examples ?